# How to get different date with the same time

Tags: php, datetime, date-arithmetic

It's maybe a really simple question but I found a little hard since I am still novice on PHP.

Presumably I have:

```
$time1 = strtotime("today 15:00:00-05:00");
```

This is just example, `$time1` is dynamic at runtime and can be any value, I would like to create new `$time2` which has the value:

```
$time2 = strtotime("this thursday 15:00:00-05:00");
```

Please note in here `$time1` and `$time2` have the same `15:00:00-05:00` and only different the day. So, to sump up, I have two inputs:

1. `$time1` which is dynamic at runtime.
2. the string `this thursday`.

How to create the `$time2` with the value like above.

Comment: Do you want to concat the two strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the difference between "today" and "today 15:00:00-05:00" and add it to "this thursday"

```
$sometime = "today 15:00:00-05:00";
$time1 = strtotime($sometime);
// now find only the hour part
$time = mktime(0,0,0, date('n', $time1), date('j', $time1), date('Y', $time1));
$time_difference = $time1 - $time; 
$time2 = strtotime("this thursday") + $time_difference;
```

Or even simpler:

```
$sometime = "today 15:00:00-05:00";
$time1 = strtotime($sometime);
// now find only the hour part
$hour_string = date('h:i:s', $time1); 
$time2 = strtotime("this thursday $hour_string");
```

Comment: This approach is little complicated for me but it does works, thanks. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: Well, using date() function you can compile the hour part of this thursday.... I'll edit the answer

Comment: The second approach does not work, it gets the different value

Comment: I think this solution will work 50 weeks a year, and break around the time of DST change :)

Answer (score 0):

Wonder why you don't use DateTime object of PHP right from the start, but ok:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($time1);
$dateTime->modify('+1 day');
$time2 = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
```

Where you can change the 1 to any amount of days.

Comment: since $time is dynamic I don't actually know how many days different, so we don't know +1 in here

Comment: So what do you know? Is it this week's thursday, even if today is friday, or is it next thursday, or what? Please specify.

Comment: $time is just an example, $time1 is just a input and can be any value which we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you want is to concat the two string "this thursday" and "15:00:00-05:00":

```
$str1 = "this thursday";
$str2 = "15:00:00-05:00";

$time = strtotime($str1." ".$str2);
```

Comment: Well, it is not like this since you don't actually know the time via string, it's dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. And you need to specify more if it is not fulfilling the requirement.

```
 $time1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $time2 = 'this thrusday ';
 $time2 .= $time1;
 $time2 = strtotime($time2);
```